# Ordenar arrays objeto con métodos

Tags: java

Buenas,

Tengo dos arrays con que introduzco por parámetros en un método. Un array contiene nombre y escudera de piloto fórmula uno, el otro contiene los tiempos de cada piloto, ahora necesito ordenar este array y mostrarlo por pantalla.

Veo que está en método sort pero no sé muy bien como se utiliza, podéis darme alguna ayuda, copio mi código...

```
public void listadoPilotosCarreraTiempo(int maximoPilotos, Piloto pilotos[], Tiempo tiempos[]) {
        System.out.println("LISTANDO PILOTOS CON TIEMPO");
        System.out.println("-----------------");
        arrays.sort(tiempos);
        for (int i = 0; i < comptadorPilotos; i++) {

            System.out.println("Piloto :" + i);
            System.out.println("Nom :" + pilotos[i].getNom());
            System.out.println("Escuderia :" + pilotos[i].getEscuderia());
            System.out.println("Tiempos : " + tiempos[i].getHoras() + ":" + tiempos[i].getMinutos() + ":" + tiempos[i].getSegundos());

        }
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que tengo la respuesta a tu pregunta. Yo cuando quiero comparar algún campo de alguna clase utilizo la interfaz Comparable. Te dejo un ejemplo de como utilizarla, en tu clase Piloyto y Tiempo.

```
/* Ejemplo Clase e Interface Comparable aprenderaprogramar.com */
public class Persona implements Comparable<Persona>{
      public int dni, edad;
      public Persona( int d, int e){
        this.dni = d;
        this.edad = e;

      }
    public int compareTo(Persona o) {
      int resultado=0;
      if (this.edad<o.edad) {   resultado = -1;      }
      else if (this.edad>o.edad) {    resultado = 1;      }
      else {
        if (this.dni<o.dni) {  resultado = -1;    }
        else if (this.dni>o.dni) {   resultado = 1;   }
        else {   resultado = 0;   }
      }
      return resultado;
  }
}
```

Entonces ahora a la hora de ordenarlo en el array solo tendrás que poner:

```
arrays.sort(tiempos);
```

Y esto lo que hace es coger por defecto el método que hay creado en la clase y lo ordena automáticamente.

Comment: Hola Eduard, era asi correcto, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Usando `java8` puedes hacer:

Creas una `List` a partir del `array`, para poder utilizar operaciones especiales

```
List<Piloto> listaPilotos = Arrays.asList(pilotos);
```

Creas un `stream`, con el que vas a ordenar en base a un método del objeto `Piloto`, y que vas a utilizar también para agrupar el resultado de la ordenación en un objeto `List<Piloto>`.

```
listaPilotos = listaPilotos.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Piloto::getEscuderia())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Así tendrías una lista ordenada por el método `getEscuderia`.
No sé por qué campo tendrías que ordenar, pero simplemente sería cambiar el bloque de `Comparator.comparing` y lo tendrías.

Comment: Perdonar es que no me he explicado bien, me suele pasar.

Comment: Veamos, mi array pilotos que es objeto contiene dos Strings ( nombre, escuderia), mi array tiempos que es objeto tiempo contiene tres int ( horas, minutos, segundos) entonces primero tendre que ordenar los tiempos, comprobando cada hora, minuto y segundo para ver cual es mas rapido, por ultimo tendre que relacionar estos tiempos con los pilotos a los que ya les habia introducido los tiempos.